# Safely evaluate string in Python to call hashlib

Tags: python

I would like to allow people to provide the name of a hash function as a means of digitally fingerprinting some object:

```
def create_ref(obj, hashfn='sha256'):
    """
    Returns a tuple of hexdigest and the method used to generate
    the digest.

    >>> create_ref({}, 'sha1')
    ('bf21a9e8fbc5a3846fb05b4fa0859e0917b2202f', 'sha1')
    >>> create_ref({}, 'md5')
    ('99914b932bd37a50b983c5e7c90ae93b', 'md5')
    """
    return (eval('hashlib.%s' % hashfn)(unicode(obj)).hexdigest(), hashfn)
```

Is hard coding `hashlib` sufficently robust to prevent abuse of `eval`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of eval, try this code:

```
def create_ref(obj, hashfn='sha256'):
    """
    Returns a tuple of hexdigest and the method used to generate
    the digest.

    >>> create_ref({}, 'sha1')
    ('bf21a9e8fbc5a3846fb05b4fa0859e0917b2202f', 'sha1')
    >>> create_ref({}, 'md5')
    ('99914b932bd37a50b983c5e7c90ae93b', 'md5')
    """
    allowed = hashlib.algorithms
    if hashfn in allowed:
        return (getattr(hashlib,hashfn)(unicode(obj)).hexdigest(), hashfn)
    else:
        raise NameError('Not a valid algorithm')
```

This will guarantee that the algorithm provided is a valid algorithm. (Note that hashlib.algorithms is new in 2.7, so if you use an older version, replace hashlib.algorithms with a tuple of allowed algorithms.

Comment: Just a small change for **Python3** users, to use `allowed = hashlib.algorithms_available` instead of `allowed = hashlib.algorithms`

Answer (score 4):

**No.**

If you apply some of the SQL Injection attack concepts, it would be conceviable for the user to supply something like this:

`"sha1(...); some_evil_code(); hashlib.sha1"`

Which would totally blow the "security" away by ending up like this:

`"hashlib." + "sha1(...); some_evil_code(); hashlib.sha1" + "(your-original-code)"`

Which would result in 3 statements being run (a fine one, and evil one, and a fine one).

<sup>(even if the above code has holes in it, the concept could still be exploited)</sup>

---

Instead, use the dynamic power of python to make this work!

```
TYPES = ('sha256', 'sha1', 'md5', ...)
def create_ref(obj, hashfn='sha256'):
   if hashfn not in TYPES:
      raise ValueError("bad type")

   # look up the actual method
   fun = getattr(hashlib, hashfn)

   # and call it on `obj`
   fun(...)
```

Food for thought!

Comment: eval can only take 1 expression, so this is invalid

Answer (score 1):

```
import hashlib

...
return (getattr(hashlib, hashfn)(unicode(obj)).hexdigest(), hashfn)
```

i think like this is more safely than using eval()

Comment: This is still susceptible to errors at the minimum (calling any attribute of hashlib).  He should ensure that only the "whitelisted" functions can be called.

Comment: @gahooa: this code is more EAFP so if the hash method don't exist it will raise an error that's all right :)

Comment: @gahooa: Ahh i see you did put some allowed hash method in your answer hmm , yes good point, but it's not what i understand from the OP question :), but still good you have just complete the OP question and added an answer :)

Answer (score -1):

```
TYPES = {'sha256':hashlib.sha256 , 'sha1': hashlib.sha1, 'md5': hashlib.md5, ...}
def create_ref(obj, hashfn='sha256'):
    #var 1 - use sha256 as default on invalid hashfun
    #func=TYPES.get(hashfn, hashlib.sha256)

    #var 2 raise error on invalid hashfun
    if TYPES.has_key(hashfn):
        func=TYPES[hashfn]
    else:
        raise NameError('Not a valid algorithm')
    return (func(unicode(obj)).hexdigest(), hashfn)
```